How to create radio buttons in a radio group with dividers in Android
I want the radio buttons as seen in the below image.

The outer rectangle should have corner radius and the inner rectangles cannot have the corner radius.
I have used the following method :
 <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_32"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_16"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_16"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:showDividers="middle"
            android:divider="@color/black"
            android:background="@drawable/radio_button_rectangle"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_btn_14_days"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp_16"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp_16"
                android:background="@drawable/inner_rectangle"
                android:text="@string/14_days"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_btn_30_days"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp_16"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp_16"
                android:background="@drawable/inner_rectangle"
                android:text="@string/30_DAYS"/>


        </RadioGroup>

Outer rectangle:
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="@dimen/dp_1" android:color="@color/black"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/transparent"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
</shape>

the inner rectangle:
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid
        android:color="@color/transparent" />
    <stroke
        android:width="@dimen/dp_1"
        android:color="@color/black" />
</shape>


The problem with this approach is that the inner rectangle does not have corner radius and does not align at the corners. Also the dividers become darker since the ends are overlapping. I have also tried using divider attributes in the radio group which does not add the dividers. How can I achieve this.

If I have understood your question,you want the radio group to have corner radius and not the inner rectangles(radio button)? if so just place the radio group inside a cardview then give it corner radius

But in that case, it will overlap with the inner rectangle which I have given to create a divider between the radio buttons. @Tommly Jumah
